# How to serialize struct in similar way as simple value types (Guid, System.Int32)

Tags: c#, serialization

I have simple type `struct`. Which is implicty convertible to well known simple types like `int` or `byte`.

My `struct` has no properties so usage is like

```
int i = 1;    
MyStruct a = i;
```

or

```
MyStruct a = MyStruct.Empty;
int i = (i)a;
```

code is working. However I have problem with serialization: I would like to serialize my `struct` in the same way like `System.Int32` or `Guid` are.

`ToString()` is working without problem, also in debugger everything is looking ok. Struct is marked as `Serializable`

**New EDIT:**

The problem with serialization is - my `struct` is not serializaing. In serialized text (e.g. JSON) it is empty string. When I would like to see value the same as returned in `ToString()`

For serialization I'm using:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public Guid Id { get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public MyStruct A { get; set;}
}

var myclass = new MyClass() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); A = MyStruct.MyNewStruct() }
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
```

Guid is serializing - *Id: "...guid..."*, 
A is not -  *A: ""*

When I add property to my struct e.g. Value - then it serializes to:
A: [Value: "myvalue"]

I would like to avoid this Value part.

Comment: "I have problem with serialization" - Going to give us a clue then? What goes wrong?

Comment: Does this compiles for you `MyStruct a = int i;` ?

Comment: Yes it is compiling because I have implicit operator inside MyStruct

Comment: But isn't the correct code actually `int i; MyStruct a = i;`?

Comment: Please send your serialization-related code, too.

Comment: Have you added the `Serializable` attribute?

Comment: I don't have any special code, I looked into System.Int32 or Guid code and the only part related to serialization I found was Serializable attribute which I've added. To serialize struct I'm using JsonConvert.

Comment: Yes `MyStruct` has `Seriazable` attribute

Comment: You can help Json.Net in serialization process by writing a custom converter `public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
        { /* ... */
        }`

Comment: I know, but I would to have something more generic to not relay only JsonConvert

Comment: Is the member of the struct where the value is stored `readonly`?

Comment: I tried both, readonly and not readonly. No luck.

Comment: Is this question strictly json-related? If yes, you could add a tag. If not and you're ok with binary serialization I might post some further suggestions.

Comment: not strickly JSON, any "string" serialization, xml, DataContract, JSON. I just want plain string without properties after serialization.

Comment: Can no one answer this? There has to be a simple way to do this.